# How to vuelidate at least one of the input is filled?

Tags: vuelidate

Should I use `validationGroup` or `or validator` to validate no1 OR no2 is required?

I have to input areas. Form should be **valid only if one of areas are filled**.

```
no1 > 0 || no2 > 0
```

[image: input areas]

Please Check [question repo](https://github.com/cemkaan/vuelidate/blob/735401125b9ad90e2d8fcad6507c6d4922c60370/src/components/OneOfNumbers.vue#L32).